# Border bottom smaller than the text

Tags: html, css, border

I have this html code:

```
<h1>FROZEN</h1>
```

And I want a border bottom for this element, a border to look like this one:

[image]

Maximum 150px width border. Is there any css solution to achieve this?

Comment: what have you tried? from your reputation I guess you know this is a poorly asked question. you need to provide code. one solution could be a create a div to do the style you want

Comment: place your code here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this using `::after`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9tymspx/)

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size:64px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

h1::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:1px;
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

You can use `float:left` or `float:right` to get your text to to align left or right, however you want.

This way, you don't need any extra HTML elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
<h1>FROZEN</h1>
<hr width="150px" />
```

Comment: the hr will be center aligned ?

Comment: Yes, you can also do it by yourself whether you want it left, right or center aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do something like this is use Pseudo-classes like `::before` `::after` 
 [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/usmanarshad87/pen/PqpPRo)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to simply use the HR tag and apply a width.

```
<hr width="5%"/>
```

Comment: Credit to @Amanjot Kaur, using px instead of % is a better idea.